# Problem with build agent demands not validated for android build

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, azure-devops, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I've included my own machine as DevOps Build Agent. This machine can build Android Apps without problems. But still it complains about demands not met:

java
JDK
AndroidSDK
vstest
Agent.Version -gtVersion 2.116.0

I installed the latest Java Development Kit 8, this should add java and JDK, but still it complains. Agent version is newer than 2.116, and latest Visual Studio is installed on the machine.

Could anyone guide me in the right direction here. I can't see anything missing on the machine, but still it's not valid for the Agent Pool to build Xamarin Android Apps.

Comment: I solved this by adding a manual "AndroidSDK" variable to the agent

Comment: You could [add it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to close this thread. It could help more communities who have the same issue .

Comment: @AtleS you save my life

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that this is resolved in the latest version of the agent.  There is some discussion on the repo that looks like this [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/1043).  The workaround you mentioned worked in comments about adding AndroidSDK variable to the agent is also captured in the discussion there.